# Can s7 Wall charger be used on s8?

Tags: samsung, charging

Can I use Samsung Galaxy s7 wall Charger on S8?

I'm concerned about damaging the s8. and could not find real solid specs online.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. I always used a charger from different phones, never had a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a supplemental answer to what @beeshyams already wrote...

S7 comes with a EP-TA20 series charger, capable of QC 2.0, rated for 9V 1.67A or 5V 2A.

[image]

On the other hand, S8 comes with a EP-TA200 series charger, which is near identical to the former one, except that its USB port has been moved from the side to the top, and comes with a USB-C cable by default.

[image]

Safe to say that as long as you get the USB-C cable right, the two makes no difference.

(Pictures courtesy of [chongdiantou.com](http://www.chongdiantou.com/), a Chinese forum dedicated to chargers and batteries)

Comment: +1 Andy. I saw something similar researching he specs but couldn't obviously decipher Chinese :)

Answer (score 5):

[Samsung says](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00062591/)

> ....You can charge your phone using any **Samsung-approved wall charger**, but charging speeds may vary depending on the charger....

Further this [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GalaxyS8/comments/6dc6yp/galaxy_s8_charging_voltage_and_observations/) claims that S7 and S8 use the same charger

I am not sure what is the difference in charging speeds

In the absence of specs , it is not possible to say for sure, but I wouldn't hesitate since both chargers are Samsung and apparently similar as pointed in the reddit.